# I am trying to put a grayscale into a bigger black image. I am getting this error OpenCV Error: Assertion failed

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv. I am trying to put a grayscale into bigger black image and my code is below.

```
Mat  imageGray, padded;

imageGray= imread("/home/nick/workspace/trial/src/imageGray.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

int padding  = 20;

padded.create(imageGray.rows + 2*padding, imageGray.cols + 2*padding , imageGray.type());

padded.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0));

imageGray.copyTo(padded(Rect(padding, padding, imageGray.rows, imageGray.cols)));

imshow("Trial",padded);
```

I am getting assertion error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sintax for creating a Rect is `(x,y,WIDTH,HEIGHT)`,  try:

```
imageGray.copyTo(padded(Rect(padding, padding, imageGray.cols, imageGray.rows)));
                                                           ^               ^
```